# Put markers in the maximum values in a Plot

Tags: plotting

I have made my graph of a list of data with the following code:

```
 ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

So this way I can see some markers in the graph but the problem is that I only need the markers in the maximum values because my plot has a kind of oscillatory behavior so I need to see the markers only in the peaks of my graph. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Fake data (next time please provide your own data)

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 4 Pi, Pi/100}];
```

The points with maximum ordinate ("y" value) can be found with [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) and [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html).

```
MaximalBy[data, N@*Last]
```

> ```
> {{Pi/2, 1}, {(5 Pi)/2, 1}}
> ```

`N@*Last` stands for the `Composition` (`@*`) of `N` and `Last`, i.e `N[Last[#]]&`

To add them into your plot use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
ListLinePlot[
 data
 , Epilog -> {
   PointSize[Large]
   , Red
   , Point[MaximalBy[data, N@*Last]]
   }
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Same for `MinimalBy` values.

```
ListLinePlot[
 data
 , Epilog -> {
   PointSize[Large]
   , Red
   , Point[MaximalBy[data, N@*Last]]
   , Blue
   , Point[MinimalBy[data, N@*Last]]
   }
 , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the local rather than just the global maximums

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0., 4. Pi, Pi/100.}];

peaks = data[[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]]

(*  {{1.5708, 1.}, {7.85398, 1.}, {12.5664, 1.2865*10^-15}}  *)

ListLinePlot[data,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[peaks]}]
```

[image]

Note that the right boundary point is also a peak (local maximum).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mark maxims and minims and found this work

```
data = Table[{i, Sin[i]/(1 + 0.1 i)}, {i, 0., 12. Pi, Pi/200.}];

peaksx = data[[FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]];
peaksn = (-data)[[FindPeaks[(-data)[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]];

ListLinePlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[peaksx]}, {Blue, 
    AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[-peaksn]}}]
```

[image]